# Is there a way to enforce the implementation of interface methods in Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, interface

I'm currently developing a central authentication API(in ruby on rails) which will authenticate with many other providers based on the domain of a user's email address.

If I was using java, this would be a classic use case for interfaces. Given that I am using Ruby, I would still like to use the interface construct, but not really sure how to enforce the implementation of interface methods.

The intention for this interface is to have one `authenticated?` method, for now at least.

An example implementation. It authenticates a user in a local database.

```
# internal_user.rb
class InternalUser < User
  def authenticated?(email, password)
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: email)
    user && user.valid_password?(password) && !user.confirmed_at.nil?
  end
end
```

So when I add more provider support to my API(i.e. more classes that implement this interface), how can I ensure that these new classes are going to implement this interface, in other words, ensure that the `authenticated?` method has been implemented?

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://shiroyasha.io/interfaces-in-ruby.html

Comment: Ruby does not have abstract classes, methods or interfaces but it gives you the tools to build it if you really need it. But in the end YAGNI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have any interface similar to Java. With [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), it's up to each class to decide if it answers a method call or not.

If you want to show that a method should be implemented in a subclass, you could raise an exception in the parent method :

```
class User
  def authenticated?(*p)
    raise NotImplementedError, "IMPLEMENT ME IN #{self.class}##{__method__}"
  end
end

class InternalUser < User
end

InternalUser.new.authenticated?('user', 'user@test.com')
#interface.rb:3:in `authenticated?': IMPLEMENT ME IN InternalUser#authenticated? (NotImplementedError)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to use duck-typing to force the method implementations